# Linq Limit/Group by Id when joining IQueryables

Tags: entity-framework, linq

I have a list of ids, that I then have multiple IQueryables that at the end I am joining to return my results. However some of these queries could have multiple records for that particular ID and I only need 1 record per ID from my set of x IDs. For example there could be 1 Name record, 3 Addresses, 2 Emails, 4 Phones for a single ID, but I only need 1 of each, does not matter which if multiple exist.

```
var clientNames = (
            from n in db.Names
            join cnl in db.ClientNameLinks on n.name_id equals cnl.name_id
            where request.Ids.Contains(cnl.client_id)
                  && n.name_id > 0
                  && n.nametype_id != null
            select new
            {
                n.display_name,
                cnl.client_id
            });
var clientAddresses = (
            from a in db.Addresses
            join cal in db.ClientAddressLinks on a.address_id equals cal.address_id
            where request.Ids.Contains(cal.client_id)
                && a.address_id > 0
            select new {
                a.display_address,
                cal.client_id
            });
var clientEmails = (
            from e in db.Emails
            join cel in db.ClientEmailLinks on e.email_id equals cel.email_id
            where request.Ids.Contains(cel.client_id)
                && e.email_id > 0
            select new { 
                e.email_address,
                cel.client_id
            });
var clientPhones = (
            from p in db.Phones
            join cpl in db.ClientPhoneLinks on p.phone_id equals cpl.phone_id
            where request.Ids.Contains(cpl.client_id)
                && p.phone_id > 0
            select new {
                p.phone_num,
                cpl.client_id
            });
var rows = await (
            from n in clientNames
            join a in clientAddresses on n.client_id equals a.client_id into n_a
            from na in n_a.DefaultIfEmpty() //LEFT JOIN
            join e in clientEmails on n.client_id equals e.client_id into n_e
            from ne in n_e.DefaultIfEmpty() //LEFT JOIN
            join ph in clientPhones on n.client_id equals ph.client_id into n_p
            from np in n_p.DefaultIfEmpty() //LEFT JOIN
            select new PiiDiamondClient
            {
                ClientId = n.client_id,
                DisplayName = n.display_name,
                DisplayAddress = na.display_address,
                EmailAddress = ne.email_address,
                PhoneExtension = np.phone_ext,
                PhoneNumber = np.phone_num
}).Distinct().ToListAsync();
return rows.OrderBy(x => x.ClientId).ToList();
```

Comment: First I'd recommend to use [navigation properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#definition-of-terms) instead of joins. Makes querying a lot easier. It may also make it easier to get the results in one query statement.

Answer (score 0):

Your last query can be rewritten in the following way. It will exactly get one record from JOIN which can multiply result set.

```cs
 var query =
    from n in clientNames
    from a in clientAddresses.Where(a => n.client_id == a.client_id)
       .Take(1).DefaultIfEmpty() //OUTER APPLY or LEFT JOIN on ROW_NUMBER query
    from e in clientEmails.Where(e => n.client_id == e.client_id)
       .Take(1).DefaultIfEmpty() //OUTER APPLY or LEFT JOIN on ROW_NUMBER query
    from ph in clientPhones.Where(ph => n.client_id == ph.client_id)
       .Take(1).DefaultIfEmpty() //OUTER APPLY or LEFT JOIN on ROW_NUMBER query
    select new PiiDiamondClient
    {
        ClientId = n.client_id,
        DisplayName = n.display_name,
        DisplayAddress = a.display_address,
        EmailAddress = e.email_address,
        PhoneExtension = ph.phone_ext,
        PhoneNumber = ph.phone_num
    };
```